# Magento2 How to dbug Abstract error

Tags: magento2

Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in /var/www/html/alpha_upgrade/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:122

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Add more details like the full backtrace or what you are doing....because yes instantiate an abstract class is not possible, that means you call a wrong class somewhere.